# Calling a Node Application from Chrome's nativeMessaging API

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension

### Barebones Sample

I have an extension which I load in developer mode (have tried as both packed and unpacked extensions). It consists of three parts:

1. manifest.json
2. main.html
3. main.js

And an application which itself consists of three parts:

1. app.js
2. app.bat
3. node.json

#### Desired State

When I run `node app.js` from the command line the program functions as expected.

app.js source code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var encoding = "utf8";
var launch = new Date();
var logFile = "C:\\Users\\Jason.Nichols\\Desktop\\Node\\log.txt"

function fileLog(arg){
    var d = new Date();
    var e = d.toString() + " ";
    if(typeof arg != 'string'){
        arg = util.inspect(arg)
    }
    fs.appendFileSync(logFile, "    " + e + arg + "\n");
}


fileLog("Process Launched");

try {
   
    process;

    fileLog("Process exists");
   

    process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
      var chunk = process.stdin.read();

      if (chunk !== null) {
        fileLog(chunk);
        process.stdout.write('{"data": "' + chunk +'"}');
      }
    });

    process.stdin.on('end', function() {
      fileLog("EOL")
      process.stdout.write('end');
    });

    fileLog("Resume")
    process.stdin.resume();
   

}catch(e){
    fileLog(e);
}

fileLog("Leaving");
```

Which, as you can see doesn't do anything fancy, and in the command line it just echos back whatever it gets.

I can see all my logs in my `logfile.txt`, and generally there is joy.

#### However...

When run in the context of my extension, I get:

```
18:06:21:031 Connecting to native messaging host com.google.chrome.node.sample
18:06:21:065 Completed connecting to native messaging host com.google.chrome.node.sample (31ms)
18:06:21:185 Failed to connect: Native host has exited. (150ms)
```

in my browser.

When I inspect further by `fileLog`ing every thing, I find that when chrome runs the file via `app.bat`, my logFile gets the following error:

```
Mon May 12 2014 18:43:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) { [Error: EINVAL, invalid argument] errno: 18, code: 'EINVAL', syscall: 'uv_pipe_open' }
```

This is decidedly not good.

#### My Question:

What is `errno: 18`, and why does it only appear when run in Chrome and not from the command line? If it's any help I'm running Win7x64, Chrome 34, and Node 0.10.26.

My intuition is that the issue is related to [`SIGPIPE`](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#The_special_problem_of_SIGPIPE) or some other signal being sent to my Node process from Chrome, but that's as far as I've sussed out. Any help would be much appreciated since I'm getting the same type of behavior from Python scripts being run via nativeMessage (obviously not the same error code, but the browser fires the `onDisconnect` event and its bound listener).

#### Miscellaneous

I've set the appropriate registry values, and the other files can be viewed [here](https://github.com/ceojasonnichols/nativeMessageTest)

Comment: Any luck? I've been fighting this, too. =(

Comment: Nope. I can launch the node app, but stdio is busted, so I've been using sockets over localhost as a work around.

Comment: It was fixed [here](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/ba47e68824dbd00c51d2c659ab05a83989283aab). No release yet (stable or even unstable), but I just built Node from master and my host now works on Windows. =)

Comment: Jason, if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the heads up!